# Yii2 echo variable outside dataprovider to gridview

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-basic-app

```
<?php
$query1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(["DATE_FORMAT(approvedate, '%m-%Y') as c_date", 'sum(totalhours) as total', 'count(sku) as sku'])
        ->from('sku3d')
        ->where(['status' => 'Approved'])->orWhere(['status' => 'Cancelled'])
        ->groupBy('c_date', 'status');

        $dataProvider1 = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query1,
    ]);

        echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider1,
    'columns' => [
        'c_date:text:Month',
         [
        'header'=>'Cancelled SKU',
        'value' => function($data) {
              return Sku3d::getCancel();
         }
    ],
        'sku:text:Total Sku',
        'total:text:Total hours',

    ]
]); 

?>
```

My model:

```
public function getCancel()
{
    return (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(["DATE_FORMAT(approvedate, '%m-%Y') as c_date"])
    ->from('sku3d')
    ->where(['status' => 'Cancelled'])->groupBy('c_date')->count();
    }
```

I used the code above to count all the approved products and cancelled products as total. I need to count how many cancelled sku **each month** and list it in another columnm, now it list all without group by month. Example: In november there are 1 cancelled sku (2 hours) and 1 approved sku (4 hours) and in december there are 1 approved sku, no cancelled, it should show:

```
Month   Cancelled   Sku  Hours
11-2017    1         2     6
12-2017    0         1     3
```

Right now it showing:

```
Month   Cancelled   Sku  Hours
11-2017    1         2     6
12-2017    1         1     3
```

I'm stuck here, please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: use a custom function and a call back in your grid view.

Comment: can you show me example? thank you

Answer (score 0):

in your view:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider1,
    'columns' => [
        'c_date:text:Month',
        [
            'header'=>'any title',
            'value' => function($data) {
                  return ModelName::getCountSomething();
             }
        ],
        'sku:text:Total Sku',
        'total:text:Total hours',
    ]
]);
```

In your Model:

```
public static function getCountSomething()
{
    return (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('*')
    ->from('sku3d')
    ->where(['status' => 'Cancelled'])
    ->count();

}
```

something like that.

Comment: I used group by "c_date" and it show "Call to a member function getCountSomething() on array"

Comment: Hi @Kalu, it worked, thank you a lot, but still not what I need yet. I've edited my question, please advise. Again, thank you.